# Stop php exec() using set_time_limit

Tags: php, exec, infinite-loop

I can stop

```
exec("Ping www.google.com");
```

Using "ini_set('max_execution_time', 5)" or "set_time_limit(5)"
but not

```
exec("java myclass"); //infinite Loop class
```

why? and how I can stop the exec()?

let's say the java class that I want to run contain:

```
for(int A = 0; A == 0;)
{
    System.out.println(A + " ");
}
```

how to stop them using PHP?

**Note:** I can't edit the java file (I also want to run different class that doesn't infinite running)

Comment: What I would try to do is launching the process in background getting his PID (with something like '& echo $!' at the end of the command), and then the kill this process (with the PID) at the moment I need it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to create one `exec.php` file place your code inside

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 5)
exec("java myclass");
?>
```

and where you need execute `exec("PATH/exec.php")` instead of `exec("java myclass")`;

Comment: it's only open exec.php on notepad, any suggestion?

Comment: i don't understand what notepad you mean ? my suggestion was to place `<?php exec("PATH/exec.php") ?>` in your php script instead `exec("java myclass");` call and add instead of `PATH` path to `exec.php` that shouldn't open any notepad

Answer (score 0):

As [documentation](http://php.net/set_time_limit) explains, that's just not portable:

> The set_time_limit() function and the configuration directive
>   max_execution_time only affect the execution time of the script
>   itself. Any **time spent on activity that happens outside the execution
>   of the script such as system calls using system(), stream operations,
>   database queries, etc. is not included** when determining the maximum
>   time that the script has been running. This is **not true on Windows**
>   where the measured time is real.

Yet in practice I've found that Windows doesn't necessarily work this way. So rather than non-portable I'd say it's just not possible.

You'll have to use more advanced [Process Control Extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.fileprocess.process.php), typically something like [PCNTL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php).

Comment: can you explain the different of "exec('ping www.stackoverflow.com)" with exec("java myclass"), I think it's same because both of them run in CMD - still thx for your information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the proc_ functions to get better control. You will find it in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/de/ref.exec.php).
Below you find code you might find useful. It works only under windows, you need a different kill routine on linux. The script terminates the (else endless running) ping process after approximatly 5 seconds.

```
<?php
function kill($pid){ 
    return stripos(php_uname('s'), 'win')>-1  ? exec("taskkill /F /T /PID $pid") : exec("kill -9 $pid");
}

$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
    2 => array("file", "tmp/error-output.txt", "a+") // stderr is a file to write to
);

$process = proc_open("Ping www.google.com -t",$descriptorspec,$pipes);

$terminate_after = 5; // seconds after process is terminated

usleep($terminate_after*1000000); // wait for 5 seconds

// terminate the process
$pstatus = proc_get_status($process);
$PID = $pstatus['pid'];

kill($PID); // instead of proc_terminate($resource);
fclose($pipes[0]); 
fclose($pipes[1]); 
proc_close($process);

$time = microtime(true) - $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"];
echo 'Process terminated after: '.$time;
```

Comment: usleep() make php  wait for 5 seconds right? but if other java class that I want to run is finish just in 3 seconds, that means PHP still need to wait for 5 seconds?

Comment: You can use the `proc_get_status()` method to check if your java application is still running or is finished or was terminated. Just check the status every second, and you will be fine.